# Можно ли узнать имя ветки с которой переключился на другую?

Tags: git

Есть ли возможность узнать имя ветки с которой переключился на другую через checkout?
То есть историю операций?

Comment: Посмотрите `git reflog`. Но вообще неплохо бы уточнить зачем вы это хотите

Comment: Просто интересно. Переключился на другую ветку, посмотреть. А какая до этого была не вспомнил.

Comment: Переключится на предыдущую ветку можно командой `git checkout -` (в новых версиях ещё можно `git switch -`)